# Validation for fields into form no for all fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want after click on button(Click Me), validation check just for `field 2-1` and `field 2-2` no for all files that has class `.required` (... .closest('form')...), how is it in my code?

**DEMO:** (in here when that you click on button it work for all field that have class .required but i want just check field into form `closest('form')`): http://jsfiddle.net/ZsPyy/2/

```
function required_valid() {
    var result = true;
    $('.required').each(function () {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            //var cssObj=;
            $(this).css("background", "#ffc4c4");
            result = false;
        }
        $(this).keyup(function () {
            $(this).css("background", "#FFFFEC");
        })
    });
    return result;
}
$('button').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var passed = true;
    //passed = required_selectbox() && passed;
    passed = required_valid() && passed;
    if (!passed) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code: http://jsfiddle.net/ZsPyy/4/

I have passed the button to the `required_valid` function. So we can get the btn's parent form.

```
function required_valid(btn) {
    var result = true;
    $(btn).closest("form").find('.required').each(function () {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            //var cssObj=;
            $(this).css("background", "#ffc4c4");
            result = false;
        }
        $(this).keyup(function () {
            $(this).css("background", "#FFFFEC");
        })
    });
    return result;
}
$('button').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var passed = true;
    //passed = required_selectbox() && passed;
    passed = required_valid(this) && passed;
    if (!passed) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: i change in html code with it what i want but it don't work true, please see it yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/ZsPyy/7/

Comment: A form within a form is not allowed.

Comment: But i should use a form within a form, did can fix this problem?

Comment: It is not possible, the browser removes the form thats within another form. Because it's not Valid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
function required_valid(sbtn) {
    var result = true;
    $(sbtn).closest("form").children('.required').each(function () {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            //var cssObj=;
            $(this).css("background", "#ffc4c4");
            result = false;
        }
        $(this).keyup(function () {
            $(this).css("background", "#FFFFEC");
        })
    });
    return result;
}
$('button').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var passed = true;
    //passed = required_selectbox() && passed;
    passed = required_valid(this) && passed;
    if (!passed) {
        return false;
    }
});
```